# How to create grep alias with arguments

Tags: linux, bash, grep, alias

Lets say i have this search term:

```
grep -i -r --include=*.xib "img_28301.png" ./
```

how would i go about creating an alias that allows me to do this:

```
xibsearch img_28301.png
```

and do the same thing?

Comment: I can imagine a `search xib img_28301.png`, but not to have a variable name of alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be much cleaner to have a function for this:

```
xibsearch() {
    grep -i -r --include=*.xib "$1" ./
}
```

As alias doesn't support positional parameters.

Comment: where would i put this to run in the command line every time i start a termini?

Comment: You can place it in your `~/.bashrc` is using BASH

Answer (score 2):

As @anubhava points out, functions are generally the way to go here.

However, in this case, if you *really must* use an alias, you can rearrange the grep a bit as follows:

```
alias xibsearch='grep -i -r --include=*.xib -f - ./ <<<'
```

The `-f -` tells grep to use expressions from a file, but since thew file here is `-`, then the expressions are read from stdin.  Then we use a bash here-string to redirect the contents of a string to the stdin.  This allows the grep expression to be placed right at the end of the command, which is what we need for an alias to work.

Thus, if you call:

```
xibsearch img_28301.png
```

the alias will resolve to the following command:

```
grep -i -r --include=*.xib -f - ./ <<< img_28301.png
```

---

I'd use with the function if I were you ;-).

Comment: Nice, but I'll go with the function first.  I'll also try this.