# quick grep on constant dir

Tags: unix, grep

I need to write a lot of 'grep -I -r "some random phrase" /constant_directory'
because I am looking recursively in a certain directory. 
is there a way to do that:
(for example gr) -> gr "some random phrase" 
and it will operate exactly like grep -I -r "some random phrase" /constant_directory.
I saw a post that you recommended some dude to use a function but I didn't succeed to do that.
I am newbie in unix shell/bash

thanks

Comment: Linking to the post you found and showing what you tried and how it failed would be a good idea. Because, yes, a function is the answer here and it should be just a one-liner.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680908/how-to-create-grep-alias-with-arguments

Comment: The answer on that question is virtually **exactly** what you need. Minus the `--include` argument. Did you try it? Did it not work somehow?

Answer (score -1):

create a little shell

```
echo 'grep -Ir $1 /constant_directory/' > find_in_constant.sh
```

then just

```
chmod +x find_in_constant.sh
```

and use it like

```
./find_in_constant.sh 'some text'
```

Comment: A script is inefficient for this. A function is much better. This script is also broken for exactly the example you gave. Did you try it? Using a wildcard on a recursive `grep` call is also inefficient and will cause `grep` to miss dot-files and dot-directories.

Comment: Etan, so how would you write the function and how do you use it?
and where do I define it so in every login I can use it?

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the wildcard. I've deleted it.